# No data added to MongoDB database collection on POST request through Postman

Tags: mongoose, jwt, mongodb-query, web-development-server, http-method

I'm building a server-side code to emulate a signup/signin page. If a user tries signing up with a registered email/username, or tries to sign in with an unregistered username, a 403 will be thrown at them. When a new user signs up, a JWT is sent from the server.

```
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const jwtPassword = "123456";
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(
      "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.iom1t.mongodb.net/";
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", {
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
});

async function userExists(username, password) {
    await User.findOne({email: username})
}

app.post("/signup", async function(req,res){
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const name = req.body.name;
    if (userExists(username, password)) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            msg: "User exists in our in memory db",
        });
    }
    const newUser = new User({
        email: username,
        password: password,
        name: name
    })
    User.save({newUser}).then(() => console.log("added new User to db"))
})

app.post("/signin", async function (req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    if (!userExists(username, password)) {
        return res.status(403).json({
            msg: "User doesn't exist in our in memory db",
        });
    }

    let token = jwt.sign({ username: username }, password);
    return res.json({
        token
    });
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{console.log("server running on port 3000")});
```

When I send POST requests on the `/signup` route, the response is always the same Token for all combinations of usernames and passwords. When I send POST requests on the `/signin` route, the response is always that there's no registered user in the database, even when I enter correct details.

In the `/signin` problem is because of using `jwtPassword` instead of `password`, different tokens are generated for the same user instead of the 403 message. Converting the `userExists()` function into an asynchronous one is not helping either.

I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72199182/im-unable-to-add-data-to-mongodb-database) by replacing the last line in the `/signup` post request but to no avail

```
User.create({newUser}).then(() => console.log("added new User to db"))
```